# Kurtosis function in Julia

Tags: matlab, julia, probability, kurtosis

So I've been playing around with Julia, and I've discovered that the function to calculate the kurtosis of a probability distribution is implemented differently between Julia and MATLAB.

In Julia, do:

```
using Distributions
dist = Beta(3, 5)
x = rand(dist, 10000)
kurtosis(x) #gives a value approximately around -0.42
```

In MATLAB do:

```
x = betarnd(3, 5, [1, 10000]);
kurtosis(x) %gives something approximately around 2.60
```

What's happening here? Why is the kurtosis different between the two languages?

Comment: The Kurtosis of the Normal distribution is 3. So 3 is often subtracted from the calculated Kurtosis, and then it is sometimes called the *Excess Kurtosis*. My guess, is Julia is calculating the Excess Kurtosis.

Comment: @DanGetz you are correct, [per Julia's documentation](http://distributionsjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate.html#kurtosis)

Comment: The documentation on MATLAB's [kurtosis](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/kurtosis.html) show you exactly what that calculates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained here: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35b.htm

We often use excess Kurtosis (Kurtosis - 3) so that the (Excess) Kurtosis of a normal distribution becomes zero. As shown in the [distributions.jl docs](http://distributionsjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate.html#kurtosis) that is what is used by `kurtosis(x)` in Julia.

Matlab does not use the excess measure (there is even a note in the [docs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/kurtosis.html) that mentions this potential issue).